# Как перекинуть react-native приложение на телефон

Tags: android, react-native

Доброго времени суток, вопрос кому-то покажется идиотским, но я новичок и мне трудно понять как загрузить свое react-native приложение на телефон, тестировал на виртуальном девайсе... В документацию смотрел, но как говорят "Смотрю в книгу ..." она как мне показалось написана уже как шпаргалка а не инструкция... Спасибо за понимание)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для android, если ты раньше девайс не использовал для дебага, необходимо включить developer options, почитай  - http://androidmir.org/android/4901/ , не забудь в developer options включить USB debugging, выключи эмулятор. Дальше подключи девайс к компу через USB, на девайсе выбери USB debugging. В консоле введи команду adb devices, если все ок - будет список подключенных устройств:

> List of devices attached
>   09018912   device 
>   А дальше все тоже самое что и на эмуляторе, только для вызова дебаг меню, нужно телефон немного потрясти).
>   Если хочешь просто запустить свое приложение на телефоне, можешь скопировать себе на телефон app-debug.apk и запустить,но не всегда телефон даст возможность установить не подписаний  *.apk, для этого нужно будет сделать релиз.
>   Продукция Apple отлаживается только через Xcode.
>   Здесь все норм написано http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.42/docs/running-on-device.html#running-on-device